# Preview Question Returns to Edit on Orientation Change in Android App

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When previewing a question, if you change screen orientation it closes the preview and takes you back to the edit section. In my opinion, I think it should stay on the preview.

I'm on version 0.1.42

**Update**

Updated to version 0.1.54 with same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for being persistent with this issue, you didn't think I saw this - did ya!?  It should be fixed as of version 0.1.57 coming to a play store near you.

Comment: Haha, not gonna lie, I was starting to doubt this one just a little! Tried to keep it up-to-date without giving off the "pushy" feel :)