# Tapping a [tag] markdown in a post does nothing in the Android app

Tags: bug, tags, android-app

In my question [Clicking on a Tag Searches the Wrong Tag in Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203607/222390) there are three bullet points and the first contains tags to the meta site (using this format: [Tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags)).

In the Android app, when I click on one of those tags (outlined in red in the screenshot below) the app just closes. It doesn't crash or throw any error message, just closes.

[image: tags markdown]

*Kasra stated [in a comment on the post above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203607/clicking-on-a-tag-searches-the-wrong-tag-in-android-app/203618#comment649119_203618) that the app does not close for him, but the tags don't do anything.*

If I may offer a suggestion as well, could the formatted tags in questions (those outlined in the screenshot) be displayed similar to the way they are below the questions in the app instead of a URL style?

I'm on version 0.1.72

Answer (score 0):

As of v1.0.83<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed:
tapping the [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) link on the post will search questions on the same site containing that tag.

[image: tag link] [image: searching questions on the same site containing tag]